# Buggy image Servlet

Tags: java, image, servlets

If i download a image from my image-servlet from home, everything is ok.

But if i download the image from work, the image will download, but the tcp-connection looks like never ending.

```
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest servletRequest, HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // ...
        ServletOutputStream servetOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, imageRequestWrapper.mimeType, servetOutputStream);
        servetOutputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: In which case are you using a proxy?

Comment: hm i use ajp between httpd2 and tomcat on the server. In my office i am not sure.

Comment: Hm, http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html sais: "Maximum execution time of 15 seconds exceeded!", But how can that be? I use the .close() method.

Comment: this has to do with your work network and is not related to your code.

Comment: i dont think so matt, even http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html sais its loads at least about 15sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

i finally fixed it by write the content-length. Without content-length the Header-Line

```
Encoding-Type: chunked
```

keeps the Connection alive!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your link and it works fine for me. I just can suppose that the cause of your problem is HTTP proxy or router or firewall or NAT or ??? defined at your work.

So, first you can try to disable one of these things (if it is possible). HTTP proxy is the first candidate. For other things try to contact your system administrator.

If nothing helps but this is your servlet try to post here its source code. Otherwise it is impossible to suggest anything.

Comment: how can that be? all other images (like images on google) loads successfully.

Comment: may the firewall keeps the connection open...